# Base Layers switching of OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2

I want to know what happen when we switch between the baseLayers of an openLayers Map, I mean when we switch the baseLayer, does it use the layer.setVisibility() to false for all the remaining layers or it uses map.removeLayer() for all others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many things are done when you call the map's setBaseLayer function, and setting the visibility of other baselayers to false is just one of them.

The other layers are definitely not removed from the map.

You can check the source code here: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Map.js